# Copying the style of amsthm using \newcommand \renewcommand

Tags: amsthm, pandoc

I'm trying to exactly duplicate the layout of `amsthm` without using this package.

I want this, because `pandoc` doesn't support `amsthm` (yet), and `pandoc` is used in the online LaTeX editor http://www.authorea.com which doesn't show a `.pdf` preview, but shows a `.html` preview using pandocs latex to html conversion.

So I can use `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand` and I can use the following packages in pandoc:
`amssymb`, `amsmath`, `fancyvrb`, `longtable`, `booktabs`, `url`, `graphicx`, `hyperref` and `ulem`.

I'm mostly interested in copying the style of `amsthm`, so that my documents look the same, the automatic numbering is not something I really need, but it would be cool if it possible.

So what I've come up with now is:

```
\newcommand{\thm}[2]{\textbf{#1.} \emph{#2} \\ \emph{Proof.}}
```

Which can be used like:

```
\thm{Lemma 10}{Here is the statement that will be proved.}
Here is the proof. $\blacksquare$.
```

However, the output is still different than of `amsthm`. My questions are:

1. Can I find somewhere how much space etc `amsthm` puts before the theorem, after the theorem, between the theorem and the proof etc. ?
2. How could I duplicate this output using the limited tools I've got ?

Comment: I would just look into `amsthm.sty` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

the dimensions you're looking for are set in `amsthm.sty`, but some of them
(e.g. `\topsep`) depend on the document class you're using.

the definitions of theorem objects and `proof` are separate, so your trying to
tie them together, separating them only by `\\` isn't likely to give the same
results as what you get by using `amsthm` directly.